# Surjective Endomorphisms of finitley generated modules are isomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, module-isomorphism

I wonder if my proof of the above statement is correct. I did not find my proof in the linked answers, so now I am not sure if it is correct because it seems to be a little bit too easy.

Let be $f \colon M \to M$ a surjective endomorphisms of an $R$-module $M$. Then $M$ is an $R[x]$-module by letting $x$ act as $f$. Consider the ideal $I=(x)$. Then $IM=M$ holds since $f$ is surjective and $x \in I$. We can apply Nakayama's lemma because $M$ is a finitely generated $R[x]$-module. It follows that there exists an element $g \equiv 1 \ (\mathrm{mod}\ I)$ such that $gM=0$. Because $g \equiv 1 \ (\mathrm{mod}\ I)$ means that $g$ has constant term equal to $1$, it follows $n = 0$ for every $n \in \ker f$.

[Surjective endomorphisms of finitely generated modules are isomorphisms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239364/surjective-endomorphisms-of-finitely-generated-modules-are-isomorphisms)

[Surjective endomorphisms of finitely generated modules are injective](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2314566/surjective-endomorphisms-of-finitely-generated-modules-are-injective)

Comment: After deducing that $g$ has constant term equal 1,u deduce that $f$ is invertible, i.e $f$ is an isomorphism, , with the inverse being a polynomial in $f$. Remark that the proof is exactly the same as the one found in the first link u provided!

Comment: This is exactly what I found to be a bit cumbersome. Isn't it simpler as described in more detail in the answer below, to simply insert an element $n$ from the kernel into $g$ and see that $n=0$ follows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write $g$ as $1+h\cdot x$ for some $h \in R[x].$ If $m\in M$ belongs to the kernel of $f,$ note that $0=(1+h\cdot x)m=m+h\cdot f(m)=m.$ Hence, $f$ is an injection, so an isomorphism. This is the way I have usually seen the proof finished. You can see it as Theorem 2.4 in Matsumura's *Commutative Ring Theory.* You might want to check Vasconcelos' original paper, "On finitely generated flat modules," Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 138 (1969) 505-512.

Comment: @rschwieb - Thanks for the edit. It's amazing how what you think you are writing and what you actually write can be so different.

Comment: Do you use Chrome? If you do and haven't already, I recommend the google scholar extension. It can generate such citations in a second or two.

Comment: @rschwieb - I do ue chrome, but have not used google scholar yet. I'll have to give it a go.